# Display message only in Lynx?

Tags: html, lynx

I have an image with text in it on a website. Is there a way to show the plain text in place of the image if images are disabled (including Lynx)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use alt argument of img tag

```
<img src="url" alt="alternate text"/>
```

Answer (score 3):

Use the `alt` attribute and put the text in there.